# Why is adding up parsed doubles slower than using BigDecimal in Java?

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing

Why is

- `result += Double.parseDouble(numberAsString)`

with `result` being a `double` primitive, slower than

- `result = result.add(new BigDecimal(numberAsStrings))`

with `result` being a `BigDecimal`?

Benchmarks:

```
@Setup
public void beforeEach() {
    numbersAsStrings = new String[NUMBER_COUNT];
    double currentNumber = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_COUNT; i++) {
        numbersAsStrings[i] = String.valueOf(currentNumber);
        currentNumber += 0.1;
    }
}

@Benchmark
public double addUpDoublesParsedFromString() {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
        result += Double.parseDouble(numbersAsStrings[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

@Benchmark
public BigDecimal addUpBigDecimalsFromString() {
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
         result = result.add(new BigDecimal(numbersAsStrings[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since primitives usually have the reputation of computing faster than non-primitives the results are astonishing (at least to me):

```
Benchmark                                                   Mode  Samples      Score  Score error  Units

t.n.b.n.BigDecimalVsDouble.addUpDoublesParsedFromString    thrpt        4    484.070       59.905  ops/s
t.n.b.n.BigDecimalVsDouble.addUpBigDecimalsFromString      thrpt        4   1024.567      170.329  ops/s
```

That's 1024.567 ops/s for addition of BigDecimals but only 484.070 ops/s for addition using a primitive (benchmarked in JMH).

Why is this so? If there is a way to optimise addition of `double` primitives parsed from Strings beyond the speed of `BigDecimal`, please include this in your answer.

Comment: Just a thought - Does it give the same result if you swap the order in which you run the tests?  I had one which tested ArrayLists vs Vectors (I think), and whichever one ran second was always slower (because of Garbage Collection I'm guessing).

Comment: @Rick I'm using JMH with appropriate configuration which should take care of such issues. In fact, I'm getting the same results even if I run the tests separately in individual JVM instances.

Comment: In that case the difference is almost certainly in the implementation of parsing the double vs the implementation of parsing the string to make a new BigDecimal in the BigDecimal constructor.

So ... for instance the BigDecimal might just pump it through a precompiled and optimised regex to see whether it's properly numeric, and then if so store it internally as a string (as after all it can get arbitrarily long).  Conceptually parseDouble needs to know *which* double it is, BigDecimal just needs to know that it is *a* number.

Comment: @Rick Again no, that cannot be the case. BigDecimal needs to know and fully parse what the number is to be able to perform the precise addition of all numbers, just like double. Also, JMH is set up here so that the for-loop is not folded/optimized away.

Comment: So you've eliminated all possibilities except a difference in speed between .parseDouble(..) and new BigDecimal(..), but you refuse to believe that that is the cause???  :D  Interesting.

Comment: Maybe because parsing a double is more complicated than parsing a BigDecimal?  `parseDouble` has to handle NaN, +/- Infinity and hex-formatted doubles which BigDecimal does not.

Comment: BigDecimal should use integer math and double uses floating point math. For small numbers (that fit into a long) integer math is probably faster.

Comment: @prunge Worth investigating. Then it should be possible to at least double the speed at which native doubles are parsed by adapting BigDecimals algorithm and applying it to native doubles. You could use this when the contract is that you will not receive any of those "special cases".

Comment: @Rick The question is why there is a difference in speed for .parseDouble and BigDecimal. If you want, one layer of abstraction deeper than "the reason for the difference in speed is that there is a difference in speed" ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are really doing 2 things. PARSING and ADDING, yet you are accusing the primitive addition of being slower[if you really dissect your initial question, and your comment, "Since primitives usually have the reputation of COMPUTING faster than non-primitives the results are astonishing (at least to me):"].

Perhaps the addition operation isn't the slow operation for the double. Perhaps the parsing on primitives is what is slower, while the addition of the primitives is faster. I would try many more benchmarks, like the following

```
double[] doubleValues;
BigDecimal[] bdValues;

@Setup
public void beforeEach() {
    numbersAsStrings = new String[NUMBER_COUNT];
    doubleValues = new double[NUMBER_COUNT];
    bdValues = new BigDecimal[NUMBER_COUNT]; 
    double currentNumber = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_COUNT; i++) {
        numbersAsStrings[i] = String.valueOf(currentNumber);
        doubleValues[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbersAsStrings[i]);
        bdValues[i] = new BigDecimal(numbersAsStrings[i]);
        currentNumber += 0.1;
    }
}




//additional benchmarks

@Benchmark
public double addUpDoubles() {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
        result += doubleValues[i];
    }
    return result;
}

@Benchmark
public BigDecimal addUpBigDecimals() {
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
         result = result.add(bdValues[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

@Benchmark
public void doublesParsedFromString() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(numbersAsStrings[i]);
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void bigDecimalsParsedFromString() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
         BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(numbersAsStrings[i]);
    }
}



//original benchmarks-----------------------

@Benchmark
public double addUpDoublesParsedFromString() {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
        result += Double.parseDouble(numbersAsStrings[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

@Benchmark
public BigDecimal addUpBigDecimalsFromString() {
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.length; i++) {
         result = result.add(new BigDecimal(numbersAsStrings[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Also consider the possibility that shorter numbers might parse quickly for BigDecimal while longer numbers may not. I would try the benchmark using different number ranges

Comment: Parsing a double, according to the trace I ran, uses the following code, which is too long to be posted here, so I am providing a link: 
[LINK](http://ezphonics.000webhostapp.com/parseDouble.java) which shows the main methods used, minus a few helper methods
which is an excerpt from:
[LINK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#l995).

while the BigDecimal uses the following algorithm(that requires a lot of methods I did not include)
[LINK](http://ezphonics.000webhostapp.com/BigDecimal.java)

Comment: Appreciate your input. Sure, "adding up parsed doubles" is a compound variant of both of "parsing" and of "adding up". Adding up the numbers just eliminates suggestions such as by @Rick in the comments above (e.g. unprocessed caching). As it is not the "adding up" part that that's faster, the question remains: Why is adding up parsed BigDecimals [in a selected numeric range] faster than adding up parsed doubles [despite doubles being faster by themselves]? And that's the original question I'm still hoping to find an answer for. Nobody said "doubles are always slower to add up than BigDecimals"

Comment: Did you try different number ranges?. Doubles are 64 bits but the BigDecimal representation of 1.0 can be done using a byte(which is an integer[32 bits] on the virtual machine) and integer operations might be faster on integers than doubles, especially if you are using a 32 bit version of java. Instead of using very short numbers, like [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3] in your algorithm(currentNumber += 0.1;), I would try double randomDouble = Math.random(); which will produce a random double between 0 and 1 like .72683879834230982394 and then change your part to currentNumber += randomDouble;

Comment: And the parsing may also vary depending on the values you provide. SO... I would try that thing I said. double randomDouble = Math.random(); before the loop and then increment in the loop using currentNumber += randomDouble;